# Bazel python debugging fails with code 9 while bazel run commands runs fine

Tags: python, bazel

I was trying to figure out how to debug a python project in `bazel`. For that I use `bazel` plugin for `CLion` IDE.

This is literally the structure of my project:

```
BazelTry/
├── main
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── main.py
└── WORKSPACE
```

`BUILD` file looks like this:

```
py_test(
    name = 'main',
    srcs = ["main.py"],
)
```

and `main.py` is:

```
def main():
    a = 1 + 2
    b = 3 + 4
    print(a, b, a + b)

main()
```

When I create bazel `test` configuration like
`bazel test //main:main`, everything runs just fine, no errors, test 'passes'.
However, if I hit `debug` button for the same configuration, the process fails with

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 191.7479.33)

Process finished with exit code 9
```

Does anyone know why and how would one debug `python` here?

Thanks